# I got a problem when install laravel-mobile-detect

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to add this package to my project, and I follow this :

`https://github.com/riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect`

When I running this command:

```
composer require riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect
```

My website has got an error:
[image]

Comment: did u tried `composer install` ? to make sure every packages you have installed already

Comment: thanks @RobyFirnandoYusuf, I run this composer, and agree to modify all, and it work!